# Android: How can you get framebuffer (screenshot) on rooted device?

Tags: android, screenshot, framebuffer

I tried :

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/frame.raw");
process.waitFor();
```

but it doesn't work. My device is rooted.

I see many answers that it requires rooted access, but no actual code to get the framebuffer.

I also tried glReadPixels() but no luck.

```
public void TakeScreen() {

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;

        int screenshotSize = width * height;
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL10.GL_RGBA,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
        int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[screenshotSize];
        bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
        bb = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, screenshotSize - width, -width, 0, 0,
                width, height);
        pixelsBuffer = null;

        short sBuffer[] = new short[screenshotSize];
        ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(sBuffer);
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(sb);

        for (int i = 0; i < screenshotSize; ++i) {
            short v = sBuffer[i];
            sBuffer[i] = (short) (((v & 0x1f) << 11) | (v & 0x7e0) | ((v & 0xf800) >> 11));
        }
        sb.rewind();
        bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(sb);
        saveBitmap(bitmap, "/screenshots", "capturedImage");
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to this in the end? If so, could you share how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304611/android-read-fb0-always-give-me-blackscreen/17331970#17331970

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in replicating the way the device itself handles it:

> fb = open("/dev/graphics/fb0", O_RDONLY);

check [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/system/core.git;a=blob_plain;f=adb/framebuffer_service.c;hb=HEAD)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your problem is this sign: `>`. You cannot redirect output using `exec`. What you need to do is grab the output stream of the process (which is the input stream for you) and store it to file;

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /dev/graphics/fb0");
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
...
```