# How can I get the color of a screen pixel THROUGH ADB

Tags: android, colors, screen, adb, pixel

I need to get the color information of a specific point on screen of my android phone.

Is there a way to do that through ADB?

I am now using the build-in command screencap to capture the whole screen and then read the color of the specific point. However, it is too slow.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I will post an answer to my own question. The answer maybe device-specified (nexus7 2013), and you can adjust it to your own devices.

1.Firstly, I find out that the command `screencap screen.png` is quite slow because it take most of its time converting to png file type. So, to save time, the first step is dump screen to a raw data file.

`adb shell
screencap screen.dump`

2.Check the file size. My screen resolution is 1920*1200, and the file size is 9216012 byte. Noticing that 9216012=1920*1200*4+12, I guess the data file use 4 byte to store every pixel information, and use another 12 byte to do some mystery staff. Just do some more screencaps and I find the 12 byte at the head of each file are the same. So, the additional 12 byte is at the head of the data file.

3.Now, things are simple by using `dd` and `hd`. Assuming that I want to get the color at (x,y):

`let offset=1200*$y+$x+3
dd if='screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=$offset 2>/dev/null | hd`

I get output like

`00000000: 4b 73 61 ff s 21e
sum 21e`

The `4b 73 61 ff` is my answer.

Comment: Nice solution, but why i can't perform the command when i add "| hd" to the end on the phone, but i can perform it when executing from adb.exe console? What does "| hd" do?

Comment: `hd` or `hexdump` is used to display the binary data. For example, you has "123" in a text file, and `hd THE-FILE` gets `31 32 33`. What's your command?

Comment: hi, I don't understand the coordinate well, why $y is multiply by 1200 but not 1920?

Comment: There are 1200 pixels in X direction, and thus you should multiply $y by 1200.

Comment: What does 4b 73 61 ff translate too? RGB colors? Why 4 bytes?

Comment: Replying to myself. It's Red, Green, Blue, Alpha, in this order.

Comment: why i get only "sum 0", no display like "00000000: 4b 73 61 ff"

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp#244

Answer (score 4):

If your phone is rooted and you know its `framebuffer` format you could use `dd` and `hd` (hexdump) to get the pixel representation directly from the `framebuffer` file:

```
adb shell "dd if=/dev/graphics/fb0 bs=<bytes per pixel> count=1 skip=<pixel offset> 2>/dev/null | hd"
```

Usually `<bytes per pixel> = 4` and `<pixel offset> = Y * width + X` but it could be different on your phone.

Comment: I type `adb shell "dd if=/dev/graphics/fb0 bs=4 count=1 skip=1000 2>/dev/null | hd"`, It returns `Usage: hd [-b base] [-c count] [-r delay] file`. Seems that the 'hd' is executed in my bash shell rather than the adb shell.

I try the following:

I

So

Comment: most likely you don't have `root` so `dd` does not produce any output for `hd` to process

Comment: I try the following: 
`adb shell`
`su`
`dd if=/dev/graphics/fb0 bs=4 count=1 skip=1000 2>/dev/null | hd`
It returns something like
`00000000: 00 00 00 00 s 0`
`sum 0`

Comment: Those 4 bytes `00 00 00 00` is the data you are looking for.

Comment: I am afraid not, because every skip like `skip=0` `skip=32` `skip=1000` `skip=10000` `skip=32000` returns `00 00 00 00`. BTW, my screen is not black.

Comment: Now I pull the whole fb0 to a binary file by `adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 androidFB.raw`. I check the content of the file using `hexedit androidFB.raw`, and it's truly all `00 00 00 00`. So, the problem is in `/dev/graphics/fb0`. Any ideas? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I find out. Someone has the same problem, it's relate to modern GPUs. [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304611/android-read-fb0-always-give-me-blackscreen ]

Comment: i got `C6 7A 25 62` , how to change the value to RGB?

Comment: I tried everything but couldn't get the right pixel color using this method. I had to go with the accepted answer using a screencap file. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous accepted answer, i wrote a SH function able to calculate buffer and etc to work out of the box on my phone.

usage:

```
GetColorAtPixel X Y
```

GIST : https://gist.github.com/ThomazPom/d5a6d74acdec5889fabcb0effe67a160

```
widthheight=$(wm size | sed "s/.* //")
width=$(($(echo $widthheight | sed "s/x.*//g" )+0))
height=$(($(echo $widthheight | sed "s/.*x//g" )+0))
GetColorAtPixel () {
    x=$1;y=$2;
    rm ./screen.dump 2> /dev/null
    screencap screen.dump
    screenshot_size=$(($(wc -c < ./screen.dump)+0));
    buffer_size=$(($screenshot_size/($width*height)))
    let offset=$width*$y+$x+3
    color=$(dd if="screen.dump" bs=$buffer_size count=1 skip=$offset 2>/dev/null | hd | grep -Eo "([0-9A-F]{2} )" |sed "s/[^0-9A-F]*\$//g" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' |cut -c3-8)
    echo $color;
}
```

And an alternative version, (the first one does not work for me when i embed it in an sh file for some unkown default hexdump behaviour issue)

```
widthheight=$(wm size | sed "s/.* //")
width=$(($(echo $widthheight | sed "s/x.*//g" )+0))
height=$(($(echo $widthheight | sed "s/.*x//g" )+0))
GetColorAtPixel () {
        x=$1;y=$2;
        rm ./screen.dump 2> /dev/null
        screencap screen.dump
        screenshot_size=$(($(wc -c < ./screen.dump)+0));
        buffer_size=$(($screenshot_size/($width*height)))
        let offset=$width*$y+$x+3

        color=$(dd if="screen.dump" bs=$buffer_size count=1 skip=$offset 2>/dev/null | /system/xbin/hd | awk '{ print toupper($0) }' | grep -Eo "([0-9A-F]{2})+" | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | cut -c9-14 )
        echo $color;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `hexdump -C` instead of `hd` in your first example? Maybe that would fix the embed problem.