# Unable to get an ADB shell command with a path working within a Windows shell

Tags: android, windows, shell, adb

I'm trying to get the color of a pixel from a screendump. While I can get the command to work when I use 'adb shell' first, I want to be able to run the command right from a windows shell. I've tried all the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185005/how-can-i-get-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel-through-adb), but I can't get it to work.

`"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe"  -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd`

This returns

> 'the system cannot find the path specified'

If I try:

`"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe"  -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell \"dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd\"`

It returns:

> /system/bin/sh: dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950
>   2>/dev/null | hd not found

The sh file does exist in /system/bin/ so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: `adb shell dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd` returns the same error that the system cannot find the path specified. 

The folder containing adb.exe is spelled MEmu (it's an emulator). That folder is already in my PATH environmental variable.

Other commands like `adb shell screencap /sdcard/screen.dump` work just as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to escape the `"` character for entering command for `adb shell`.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd"
```

will be OK.

Besides, your comment said,

> That folder is already in my PATH environmental variable.

Then you don't need to specify the full path to `adb`.

```
adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd"
```

is OK, too.

---

The error message,

> /system/bin/sh: dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd not found

indicates that there is no executable called "dd if='/sdcard...null | hd", but you are just need them as parameters, not a full executable name.

---

For your first attempt,

```
"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd
```

This command will regard `hd` outside of the `adb shell`, it is going to execute by the command line of Windows.

**Update**: We can use the parameter of `od` or `hd` to do some tricks.
For example, on my device, `busybox od` has the parameter `[-t TYPE]`, `[-A RADIX]`, `[-N SIZE]` and `[-j SKIP]`, then on my phone I can do

```
adb shell od -N4 -j54950 -tx1 -Ax /sdcard/screen.dump
```

Comment: @JonGoodwin This is the original author's configuration for connecting ADB to a device, maybe there is an emulator on the same machine. So I just keep it.

Comment: @JonGoodwin I am not sure if the original author's inbox will have messages for our comment**s**... But, we know, when he come back to this question, he will see our answers and comments. Besides, there will be an error if I try to mention two people, "Only one additional @ user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified".

Comment: @JonGoodwin Let's wait for the original author's return :-)

Comment: If I try 

`"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | hd"`

It returns:

`Usage: hd [-b base] [-c count] [-r delay] file`

Comment: @JoeBriggs Then it's time to try how to use `hd` in your machine. For example use `busybox hd` or `hd -`? This is something more device specific.

Comment: The MEmu android emulator is configured as a SM-G920F. `"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | busybox hd"` returns: hd-: applet not found (even if I install busybox from the playstore)..

Comment: @JoeBriggs What about `busybox hexdump`? Or use `od`, for example `od -x`?

Comment: Your suggestions are returning some interesting results.

In comparison, if I run ADB shell first and then the command it returns:

0000000: 22 74 e6 ff s 27b
sum 27b

Now this is what your suggestions return:

`"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | busybox hexdump"`

0000000 7422 ffe6
0000004

`"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | busybox od"`

0000000 072042 177746
0000004

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | busybox od -x"`

0000000 7422 ffe6
0000004

So even though the color info is returned in a different order, it is working.

Comment: Yes, that's it. `od` without parameter is an octal dump, and `hd` is an alias for `hexdump -C` on some devices, `hexdump` is a hexadecimal dump.

Comment: " So even though the color info is returned in a different order, it is working", you may try to look for the parameters of `od` or `hd` for a better format. On my device, I can use `-N` and `-j` parameter of `od` to directly dump **part** of file, then the `dd` part is not necessary for me.

Comment: "So even though the color info is returned in a different order, it is working." Try `od` with `-tx1` parameter.

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu\adb.exe" -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell "dd if='/sdcard/screen.dump' bs=4 count=1 skip=54950 2>/dev/null | -tx1 od"

Like that? It returns : system/bin/sh: -tx1 not found

Comment: @JoeBriggs Just a try for tuning the output format. You may try under the help of `--help`.