The code that obtains the rgb color code of the desired x, y coordinates with adb on java
I'm trying to do game automation via adb using java. I want to write a method that returns the rgb color code of a desired x, y coordinate without saving the ready screenshot to the computer with my click, hold, swipe methods (the process takes about 3 seconds when saved to the computer).
When I open the RGB test video on YouTube and test it, it gives problems with red and red tones. It displays correctly in other colors, but it does not print the exact result of the desired coordinate.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RGBColorAtCoordinates {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1200; // Replace with your desired x-coordinate
        int y = 500; // Replace with your desired y-coordinate

        try {
            // ADB command to get pixel color at (x, y)
            String adbCommand = String.format("adb shell screencap -p | sed 's/\\r$//' | head -c %d | tail -c %d", (x + 1) * 4, 4);
            
            // Execute adb command
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(adbCommand);
            
            // Read output
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line);
            }
            reader.close();

            // Parse RGB values from output (example, you may need to adjust based on actual output format)
            String colorOutput = output.toString();
            if (colorOutput.length() == 4) {
                int red = (colorOutput.charAt(0) & 0xff);
                int green = (colorOutput.charAt(1) & 0xff);
                int blue = (colorOutput.charAt(2) & 0xff);
                int alpha = (colorOutput.charAt(3) & 0xff);
                System.out.printf("RGB color at (%d, %d): (%d, %d, %d)\n", x, y, red, green, blue);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to get color information.");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


For red color the output is "Failed to get color information." The output for green color is "253, 253, 19"

Honestly I'm not sure what is going on in the line for adbCommand, while there are existing posts like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24185005/295004 if doing automation I would look at my answer to: Map keys to touchscreen as those projects are open-source. Once the video stream is on PC you are free to use more intensive image processing algorithms/tools.

@MorrisonChang I don't want to display. Does the project you posted "QtScrcpy" have a method to return the rgb value of a point on the screen?

@MorrisonChang I saw the code in the topic you posted, but unfortunately I couldn't do it.

adb screencap is generating a png file not a bitmap. You can load the png into a bitmap to do pixel color checking. You should at least do that to make sure your understanding of where you are looking at is correct. The other apps I mentioned require changing their respective code. A different tester type app/framework is monkeyrunner but that uses Python.

As mentioned in the comments, you are trying to obtain pixel values from a PNG file which requires decoding the PNG first.
Alternatively, you can use CulebraTester2-public which provides an API to obtain pixels, for example, when the service is running on the device you can do:
curl -s 'http://localhost:9987/v2/uiDevice/pixel?x=1200&y=500' | jq
{
  "a": 255,
  "b": 235,
  "g": 224,
  "r": 222
}

you can use nay HTTP client from Java to do it.
